# 'Responsive' email not responsive post-my interference

Tags: html, html-email, responsive, fluid-layout

Apologies in advance for code overkill. I don't have any idea where the problem lies, so I'm just going to have to paste in the whole thing. I don't think what I've been trying to build is particularly complex- but I AM now particularly out of my depth. I got misled when the previews at Email On Acid looked fine all along as I was busy editing away, copy pasting code and viewing the result as I went along. But when I sent the email to my Android device there wasn't any stacking for the small screen. All three columns are rigidly there and the text has not adapted.

I've realised belatedly after researching this as much as I could and reading an excellent article on table-based spongy/fluid design by Nicole of Merlin of Email Wizardry that media queries are not good. The template I used in EOA has them unfortunately. And now I need to repair my email newsletter before I get lynched by the committee of the non-profit I am carrying this out for gratis.

I could give up trying to build it to spec and head over to Mosaico to make something generic, but this email newsletter at least needs to contain internal links!

Could you have a squizz at my code and give even a general pointer as to where I might have gone wrong and what to do to fix it?

Thanking you in advance.  Code to follow by attached text file:

...actually the code won't even paste in here: 'formatted wrongly' I can't find any option that will allow me to communicate the code to other users here. Tried getting the content temporarily hosted, but they had a character limit my project exceeded. Could attach text file if I could find a way. Apologies for the noob questions! But really want to complete this!

Comment: You have literally zero chance of having a question like that answered here. Post minimal code, get to point.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own and quickly describe where the problem is. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the FAQ and How to ask sections.

Comment: I"ve tried hard to discover the problem, but haven't been able to. In the time permitted I am pretty sure I won't be able to, because that would involve starting from scratch; the previews were telling me all was fine when it wasn't. So I understand that the project went way past a point of error without my catching that. If not for that preview anomaly I'd have been- and thought I was being- methodical as pie.

Comment: To clarify another point- not, not asking anyone to write, but to inspect, and hoping someone could first tell me how to get the code in here. But unless I can put the whole thing in here I think I have little chance of spotting even general ballpark where the problem might lie and choosing which code to include. That's how overwhelming this thing has become. I did read the 'how to ask' section- it came with the welcome email. However my difficult is in all honesty a sweeping, general one. By the way my knowledge to far doesn't extend to tracebacks, console output.

Comment: I know some html and have was working tweaking a free template called 'Emailology Responsive Email Template. It has 1 column, 2 column and 3 column blocks that I've been duplicating, adding to etc and have done something wrong that the preview pane has failed to alert me to.  I've been working like a hardworking dog on my learning curve. And very aware that there's a lot more curve left to traverse. And hoping that someone, anyone can even HINT. If I had a possible starting point I could choose some code.

Comment: Also, I tried to paste a code snippet here and got an error message about formatting. That I was unable to rectify as well. I've given up on 'responsive' as of last night. Just have to get the thing published and try to fix it for the next issue. Pain, suffering.

Comment: Tools to share your code: https://pastebin.com/ or go through the links in this search result: https://www.google.com.au/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&ei=JuoIWr6RK8eE8wWHoorQDA&q=code+sharing+website&oq=code+sharing+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l10.28766.30404.0.32716.13.9.0.0.0.0.577.1403.2-2j1j0j1.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..9.4.1400...0i67k1j0i10k1.0.cmPam0p0ClU . Alternatively create a Google / Microsoft drive account, upload your file and share the link here. Try to extract a "key" section of your code that is responsible for formatting and and include it in question body.

Comment: There are so many Android devices. Responsive works on Android 4.4 and below, anything after 5.0 have been forced to use Gmail app. If you are after Gmail app in android then Responsive works on only the versions of Gmail app. It **only** works if you have coded media queries right, if there are any errors in your media query, the whole query gets stripped.

Comment: No code = no response from folks on SO. As others have noted, use pastebin or other site so that we can all see and help with your code challenges. You'll find many people to help as soon as you show us your code! :)

Comment: Alex, many thanks for your helpful reply. I'm so low on that curve that I couldn't even formulate the right search term 'code sharing' but was instead looking for 'temporary hosting'. Anyway, since last remarks here I've taken the to anybody else obvious step of testing the actual template I started with, and it itself was non-fluid/responsive/whatever (Understand that 'responsive' is more to do with media queries and 'fluid' is more to do with basic table design for flexibility).

Comment: So rather than repair/enhance something that is so far gone I feel I have little chance of finding the first key- or identifying code from which the problem might have arisen, for purposes of sharing it here, I''ve gone back to Mosaico. It works on my android device and that's a better start than hitherto. I"ll make something simple (but big unfortunately, because they don't want links back to site: they want a contents list and intra-document links and there are a large severality of articles.)

Comment: After I've assembled (rather than built, lets be honest) and tested the thing, i'll take the nice clean fluid/responsive code and add some internal links. And I hope that will be that.  If there's a next time I post here I hope it will be from a place of more specific conception of the cluster-f I'm dealing with. Thanks very very much again Alex, Syfer!

Comment: ..."and this has been a learning curve through purgatory of stress-induced chest pain, brought to you by noob code regurgitators' league of obscurityville"

Comment: So, as they said, no, usually no one will write code for you. And unfortunately there is a HUGE world of HTML email template dos and dont's out there. Here is [one I made](https://github.com/seanrawles/Mailchimp_Template) that should be an easy jumping off point for you.

Comment: Just to clarify for the third time scoopzilla, no writing of code was requested. INSPECTION and ADVICE were what was requested. Thanks for the link. I'll look at it now.

Comment: Yes thanks for that template. It will come in handy to reverse engineer, to learn. For now, as I said earlier, I've used the Mosaico assembler, but I'm not liking the resolution of the images which I think they might have put through a shrinking machine, so I'm going to use an image hosting service and pre-shrink my own images and redo all the image links. So far, most importantly, it's fluid. And I'll just keep studying.